# Tweedie distribution with zeros being the second most common value

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, tweedie-distribution

I want to perform a multilevel glm model. I have a continuous non-negative outcome variable (not count data), with many 1 values, second most common value at zero, and then a right tail of positive values (picture attached below).

I assume that tweedie distribution is the most suitable distribution for my data. Am I right given that zero is not the most common value?
Also, does anyone know of an r-based function that will help me determine the distribution parameters?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: How is this data generated? It looks like a strange mix of integer (0, 1) + very dispersed continuous > 1 values, which doesn't look easy to model. Might need some more info.

Comment: I've looked at a fair few simulated Tweedies and that doesn't really look much like any of the ones I have seen. Can you talk about what you're measuring?

Comment: Thank you Glen and Alex. I am measuring the L2 distance a subject is taking from one point to another. zero means that the subject stays in the same spot and doesn't move. 1 means that the subject moved to an adjacent point. >1 means that they moved farer from that point. Can you think of another distribution that is more suitable?